# Novice Needs Help - Lucene

Tags: lucene

Im doing a uni project that involves designing a website. I am in the early stages of development and just want to clarify my understanding of what I have learnt so far. My website will contain a database (SQL or Oracle possibly) with powerpoint, word and maybe some other files but mainly these.

I can use Lucene to: 
1) Search my site using keywords to find and retrieve the relevant pages 
2) Search and extract the relevant powerpoint and word files from the database

From what I gathered core Lucene will index my site and database and find the relevant pages and files. I will need to add other software though, such as crawlers and a user interface.

As I say I am new to this and it is all quite complicated at the start, but is what I have gathered so far correct?

Many Thanks,

Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You will need to create a lucene Index.

2) One way of doing is to use nutch to crawl your site and it will return you a lucene index which will have all the links/data from your website indexed.

3) I believe you can create a lucene index for a database too.